# Find longest segment

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (or a series) of measured voltage (in V) indexed by timestamps (in seconds). I want to know the duration of the longest segment (=consecutive values) of voltage greater than a threshold.

Example:

```
time voltage
0.0  1.2
0.1  1.8
0.2  2.2
0.3  2.3
0.4  1.9
0.5  1.5
0.6  2.1
0.7  2.3
0.8  2.2
0.9  1.9
1.0  1.6
```

In this example, threshold is 2.0 V, and desired answer is 0.3 seconds

Real data is made of 10k or more samples, and number of segments of values above the threshold is completly random, there is even the possibility of having only one segment with all values above the threshold.
I think the first step is too identified these segments et separate them, then perform calculation of duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `True` and `False` sequence with boolean indexing. Then use `value_counts` and `max` to get the longest sequence:

```
s = df.voltage > 2

(~s).cumsum()[s].value_counts().max()
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, I knew the way of creating sequence of True and false, but not the value_counts function. I will try it soon

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
n=2
s=df.voltage.gt(n)
df.time[s].groupby((~s).cumsum()).diff().sum()
Out[1218]: 0.30000000000000004
```

And if you need the longest duration , Notice here is from 0.6 to 0.8 which should be 0.2 second ..

```
df.time[s].groupby((~s).cumsum()).apply(lambda x : x.diff().sum()).max()
Out[1221]: 0.20000000000000007
```

Comment: I was wrong in my comment. :)  I thought I deleted before anyone read it.

Comment: Thank you for so quick answer, I'll test it in next minutes (and try to understand it)

Comment: You're right, from a mathematical point of view the duration should be 0.2s, but with that way of calculating, a 2 samples segment would lead to a 0.1s duration, and a 1 sample segment to 0.0s duration... In real life, the number of samples will be greater, and one sample more or less won't be an issue. We could consider the duration from mid to next mid samples.

Comment: @Louc if need number of sample `s[s].groupby((~s).cumsum()).count().max()`

Comment: Thank you again for your help,it help me understand things about groupby() !